# Nativescript multiple fetch http post

Tags: arrays, loops, http, fetch, nativescript

I'm facing a little problem. How should I make looping POST (Arrays of data) which I need to send one by one but waiting for earlier POST response before sending another one. Any ideas are welcome!

I'm using newest Nativescript and stock fetch module.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like a recursive call to me, something like:

```
function postData(arr, index){

let itemToPost = arr[index];

fetch('https://xyz/some/url', {
    method: 'post'
    content: json.stringify(itemToPost)// something like this


}).then(function(response) { //success

    //recursive call here 
    postData(arr, ++index)

}).catch(function(err) {
    // Error :(
});
}
```

Comment: I'll give this a try!